# vlcj: change video surface wthout stopping MediaPlayer

Tags: java, swing, video, vlcj

I am using `vlcj` to play video in a Java Swing application. I want to be able to switch from one `VideoSurface` to another during playback. This is working fine if I first stop the `vlcj` `mediaPlayer`, assign a new `VideoSurface` to it and then restart the player again. The thing is, I want the switch to work seamlessly. If I skip the stop/restart part, I am seeing a grey screen with no video being displayed in the newly assigned `VideoSurface`. According to the documentation, setting a new surface should be possible. Am I missing something?

```
final Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas();
final Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas();

ComponentVideoSurface videoSurface = null;
videoSurface = factory.newVideoSurface(canvas1);
mediaPlayer.videoSurface().set(videoSurface);

// start playback...

videoSurface = factory.newVideoSurface(canvas2);
mediaPlayer.videoSurface().set(videoSurface);
```

There is no video output on `surface2`. If I switch back to `surface1`, I can see it.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
I also tried removing the first canvas from its `Container` and adding the same reference to another one (so, I did not set a new `VideoSurface`, I just moved the existing one into another `Container`), but the effect was the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simply that you can not switch video surface while playing media.

(Well, I suppose you *can* switch it, but it won't take effect.)

You can not "re-parent" the video surface to a different container either, so for example it won't work in a docking window framework without stopping and restarting video.

My usual recommendation for something like this is instead to write a custom LayoutManager that can shift your various components around without changing the actual video surface associated to the media player.

Comment: Thanks once more for clarifying, @caprica. Although I was hoping that it would work somehow. As I need to "detach" the video surface from the UI in which it is embedded initially and move it to a stand-alone dialog, a LayoutManager won't do the trick unfortunately. Thanks again!

Comment: Is it really so bad to just play the new media player in the dialog from the same playback position of the other media player? Sure, there'll be a bit a of a glitch, but it might be acceptable. You can do some tricks like "warm up" the other media player in the dialog so it doesn't have to parse the video again. But yeah, I'm afraid this a "limitation" deep down, way past the vlcj and Java layer.

Comment: Interesting! I never thought about using a sesond media player instance to solve this problem tbh. That might work, but would be a huge effort in my special case. Stopping the player and setting it to its previous position after restarting is kind of acceptable. I'll stay with the existing mechanism for now